# Keyboard hooks in C#: Side-effects

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, keyboard-hook

I have seen a number of questions on this topic on SO and elsewhere, but I've now taken it a step further and am facing some weird behavior.

My application (an Excel add-in) installs a keyboard hook to monitor for <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key to perform some actions. The hook appears to works, as it executes the procedure I have wired with it when user presses <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. However, I see 2 strange behaviors:

1. The NumLock status turns off automatically after my hooked procedure has executed.
2. A library that my add-in is using throws `SEHException` (with message "External component threw an exception"). If I do not install the hook, the library works fine.

So I'm wondering if there's something wrong with the hook itself. I have downloaded it from a [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook), but looking at some other implementations, most of these have the same basic code.

Comment: I guess it has something to do with this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/18/1317290.aspx

Comment: @erikkallen: Not sure if I'd buy that argument, can u plz put some more light? Your argument boils down to claiming that C# or any .NET language is not safe for writing a keyboard hook, yes? Also, does Excel 2007/2010 have a dependency on any of the .NET Frameworks?!

Comment: Your hook has to be loaded into every process on the system, which means that you run into the same problems as Raymond points out.